# How to display Chinese characters correctly on remote Red-Hat machine?

Tags: character-encoding, unicode, input-method

I am using Ubuntu14.04 to connect to a remote host.

Which its version is:

Linux version 2.6.32-431.11.5.el6.yyyzzz.x86_64 (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Thu Jul 3 09:42:34 CST 2014

My upload file on that machine won't display Chinese characters correctly.
And I open a file, type randomly Chinese Character with Ubuntu `ibus input method`. And it shows:

```
~R~V�~K~B~I~W个~I~N~T�饭~T~E
```

I searched online and tried the following 2 methods:

1: examine the locale

```
It shows:

LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

Seems no problem.

2: install Chinese Language support package

I did:

```
yum install "@Chinese Support"
```

It installed 178M files on that machine.

After that, I open another file, and try typing some Chinese with ibus. But the problem remains, how to solve it?

---

**update1**
I did some more research after. I find that some characters can be typed out correctly(via Pinyin input method, ibus). like:

```
起 度 顿 客
```

They are all corresponding to their Pinyin. But there is a  automate-generated space after each character( not typed by me).

If I try to type 启，杜，盾，刻 (they have the same Pinyin as the above 4 Chinese characters). I got:

```
�~P�~]~\ ~[� ~H�
```

For my experience, if the code converting is totally messed up. When I type a Pinyin, I shall get some wired characters which look like Chinese but actually were not, and they will never correspond to that Pinyin I typed.

This time, the things are little bit different.I can type some characters correctly(with an system-generated space), and others are indecipherable.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, this may be a problem of mismatch between your locale, which is set to `UTF-8`, and the encoding of your Chineses character file, which may be encoded in `gbk`, `gb2312`, `gb18030`, or `Big-5`.

All those encoding listed above are **incompatible** with `UTF-8`.

Now, let's assume `gbk` is the encoding of your file. So when you try to show the contents of the file, a `gbk` encoded file is interpreted as a `UTF-8` file, which causes the gibberish.

#### Here comes the solution.

- Use `luit`. (Preferred)

  ```
  $ whatis luit
  luit (1)             - Locale and ISO 2022 support for Unicode terminals
  ```

  `luit -encoding gbk cat a_chinese_file.txt`

Since most (if not every) encoding in use is compatible with `ASCII`, and if you only need characters in `ASCII` and another encoding, you can use the following two methods.

- Change the encoding of your terminal

  You may considered it since this method does not require additional package to be installed.
- Change Your locale

  But I think this requires you to install the corresponding locale.

---

Some details about the Chinese encoding mentioned above.

- `gbk`, `gb2312`, `gb18030` are encodings for Simplified Chinese.

  If you are not sure which certain encoding your file is using, assume it `gb18030`.

  Number of characters contained in each encoding follows this: `gb18030` > `gbk` > `gb2312`. And the superior encoding is a superset of what follows.
- `Big-5` is the encoding for Traditional Chinese.

What's more, encoding for Simplified Chinese is sometimes refered as `CP936` (Code Page 936, I think this name comes from Windows).

Comment: About the terminal issue, I can show the Chinese characters correctly on the terminal as if the file was in my local computer, but when scp it to the remote machine, the characters become uncognizable.

Comment: By the way, when excute the luit command, I got "Warning: couldn't set locale.
Segmentation fault
"

Comment: @Zen There are too many problems to deal with files not encoded in `UTF-8`. And my suggestion is to convert your Chinese character file to be encoded in `UTF-8` if you have control over that. Then everything should be fine.

Comment: you mean luit can convert it?

Comment: `luit` cannot. Use some other tools. I'm not sure which certain tool to use on linux. On Windows, you may use `Notepad++`.

Comment: won't utf-8 on Chinese would be 'xe7xd8' stuff?

Comment: It won't. You only need Chinese fonts and appropriate encoding and decoding to show them correctly. I think `\xe7\xd8` stuff is used in code to prevent from introducing non ascii characters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16313/discussion-between-pallxk-and-zen).

Answer (score 3):

I just added this line in `~/.bash_profile`:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you need to change two files as

1) In `/etc/default/locale`

```
LANG=" en_US.UTF-8"
LANGUAGE=" en_US:en.UTF-8"
```

2) In `~/.pam_environment`

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

3) reboot