# How to write a luit command that outputs a file

Tags: terminal, character-encoding, write

I need to format a luit command so I can write a file that I'm trying to fix the encoding for. What I have right now is `luit -encoding gbk cat santi.txt`, but I would like this to have the output written in a text file.

Backstory, I am having trouble reformatting a text document that was originally Chinese characters. For whatever reason using programs such as Notepad++ and encoding websites both have not worked, and I've received error messages trying to use each of the Linux solutions offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64860/best-way-to-convert-text-files-between-character-sets). I turned to luit because I've had some success using it as described [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149348/how-to-display-chinese-characters-correctly-on-remote-red-hat-machine/149353#149353).

Anyways, the `luit -encoding gbk cat santi.txt` successfully outputs Chinese characters into my terminal. However, it only has an output of ~200 lines, and the file is perhaps 2,000 +.

Looking at the what looks like the [luit manual](ftp://www.x.org/pub/X11R6.8.2/doc/luit.1.html#sect5), the two options below seem the most promising.

```
-ilog filename
Log into filename all the bytes received from the child.
-olog filename
Log into filename all the bytes sent to the terminal emulator.
```

P.S According to `chardef` original encoding of the file is probably GB2312.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
luit -c <infile >outfile
```

the `-c` switch makes `luit` act like as a simple interpreter from stdin to stdout without its wrapping a child *(your shell by default)* in a pty and handling its i/o instead.

if you also do:

```
luit -olog /dev/tty -c <infile >outfile
```

`luit` will write to both your terminal and the outfile.

basically the `-olog` switch will log to a named file a copy of all that `luit` writes to its output as it writes it - and so it represents `luit`'s processed input, but `-ilog` would do the same for all of `luit`'s preprocessed input.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. For future reference the command that worked to simply write a file with the correct encodings was `luit -encoding gbk cat <santi.txt > new_santi.txt`